# Is there any way to put WHERE condition on ALL the columns without using multiple AND?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a Student Table with multiple Subject columns

I want to SELECT record of Students who have scored above 70 in ALL the subjects.

Is there any way to do so without using 'multiple' AND Conditions

For e.g using below query I have to specify the same AND condition for every column

SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Maths > 70 AND Physics > 70 AND Chemistry > 70... so on

I am looking for something like:

WHERE Student.* > 70

Comment: change your table structure

Comment: There is no wildcard handling of column names so one way or another you will need to list the included columns

Answer (score 4):

In essence, you need to use multiple `AND` conditions.  You can mask this using `LEAST()`:

```
where least(physics, maths, chemistry) > 70
```

However, your fundamental issue is your data model.  Instead of columns, you should have a table with one row per student/subject:

```
 Table:  StudentSubjects
 studentId    Subject    Grade
```

Then you would not need to mention each subject individually.